# python - read file add 1 to the data and write in file using data frame

Tags: python, django, csv

It is my input file. comma separated values.  It should read the file, convert that into panda dataframe. If any of the values in a row is 1, then all other columns in the same row should be 1.

**Input file(filter.txt)**

```
col1  2  3  4  5        //column example

abc,  0  0, 0, 0

def,  0, 0, 1,   

abc,  0, 1,  ,  

def,  0, 0, 0, 1 

xyz,  1,  ,  ,
```

**Expected output step 2**

```
col1  2  3  4  5  6   //6th column should be updated by 1 if there 
                                               exists any 1 from col2, 3, 4 and 5

abc,  0  0, 0, 0, 0

def,  0, 0, 1, 1, 1

abc,  0, 1, 1, 1, 1

def,  0, 0, 0, 1, 1 

xyz,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

After that it should group by column 0 and sum the values.

So, far my code is,

```
   import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/ankr/Desktop/unpx/fill', sep=",", header=None)
# data.columns = 
outputFrm = []
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    tempRow = []
    oneExist = False
    for el in row:
        if el == 1:
            oneExist = True
        if oneExist:
            tempRow.append(1)
        else:
            tempRow.append(el)
    outputFrm.append(tempRow)

df = pd.DataFrame(outputFrm, columns=['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
print df
```

**Expected output step 2**

```
abc, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
def, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2
xyz, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Error:

```
File "filter.py", line 18, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(outputFrm, columns=['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 314, in __init__
    arrays, columns = _to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5617, in _to_arrays
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5696, in _list_to_arrays
    coerce_float=coerce_float)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5755, in _convert_object_array
    'columns' % (len(columns), len(content)))
AssertionError: 6 columns passed, passed data had 5 columns
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "If any of the values in a row is 1, then all other columns in the same row should be 1" .  how does xyz, , , ,, turn into xyz, 1, 1, 1 , 1, 1 ?   And it looks like only columns to the right are turned into 1?

Comment: Sorry updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('Desktop/filter.txt', sep=",", header=None)
outputFrm = []
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    tempRow = []
    oneExist = False
    for el in row:
        if el == 1:
            oneExist = True
        if oneExist:
            tempRow.append(1)
        else:
            tempRow.append(el)
    outputFrm.append(tempRow)

df = pd.DataFrame(outputFrm, columns=None)
print df
summary = df.groupby([0]).sum()
print summary
```

Output:

```
     0   1   2   3   4    5
0  abc   0   0   0   0    0
1  def   0   0   1   1    1
2  abc   0   1   1   1    1
3  def   0   0   0   1    1
4  xyz   1   1   1   1    1

      1   2   3   4   5
0                  
abc   0   1   1   1   1
def   0   0   1   2   2
xyz   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: @Anjanaa I have updated the ans too. Logic will remains same, you have added header just make change according to that before run.
Hope this will help you. HAPPY CODING

Comment: This is not adding 6th column

Comment: Thanks. But I am facing an error. Input will have 5 columns, but output should be 6 columns. I tried to add column name. I get an error. AssertionError: 6 columns passed, passed data had 5 columns. Updated my question with code and output